# Error in Execution ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run my react code which works fine in local environment but when moving to a production server getting the following error:

```
Project is running at http://localhost:8123/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ./demo
404s will fallback to /index.html
Unable to open browser. If you are running in a headless environment, please do not use the open flag.
Hash: fe2d96361454944eaee0
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 1079ms
        Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    bundle.js     325 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
bundle.js.map     384 kB       0  [emitted]         main
   index.html  320 bytes          [emitted]         
   [2] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8123 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
   [3] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8123 7.95 kB {0} [built]
   [4] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
   [7] ./node_modules/url/util.js 314 bytes {0} [built]
   [8] ./node_modules/querystring-es3/index.js 127 bytes {0} [built]
  [11] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [12] ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
  [13] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.86 kB {0} [built]
  [14] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.05 kB {0} [built]
  [15] ./node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js 181 kB {0} [built]
  [16] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.73 kB {0} [built]
  [18] ./node_modules/html-entities/index.js 231 bytes {0} [built]
  [21] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
  [23] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
  [25] ./src/index.js 624 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
    + 11 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (24:16)

  22 | // });
  23 | 
> 24 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
     |                 ^
  25 | 

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8123 ./src/index.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Any suggestions to solve it?

Code from index.js is given below:

```
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import 'box-sizing.css/box-sizing.css';
import './bl-ui/css/main.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './bl-ui/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I've tried to set up codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-breeze-o633v
But I need to fix error in index.js.

Comment: Please post code of app. looks like you commented last lines.

Comment: how is that `production` when you are running webpack-dev-server

Comment: you probably don't want to use a webpack dev server in production
if you are using create-react-app you want to run the build script and deploy what ends up in ./build folder

Comment: @learner There were few comments which I removed, but problem still persists. Code after removing comments has been added to the question above.

Comment: @AlexanderTaran can you please provide the steps for the same?

Comment: @DimitarChristoff Yes, I just pulled the same code from git repositary and did not change the webpack-dev-server. Would it impact the execution and can be possible cause of the error?

Comment: this is nothing to do with react - the issue is you have no preset loaded for babel and webpack on your other server - you'd need to load `babel-preset-react` -> `babel-preset-es2015` (e.g. or `babel-preset-env`) in order to parse JSX. run your build and deploy the bult artifacts (eg `dist` / `build` folder), this will be compiled for whatever your target is. don't forget your polyfills also.

Comment: Thanks, @DimitarChristoff! I will follow as suggested.

Comment: @ManojGoel Let us know if the issue persists.

Comment: @learner Yes, issue still persists. I tried installing `babel-preset-react`, `babel-preset-es2015` and `babel-preset-env` but that did not change the scenario. Also, executed `build` script instead of `devserver` but that also failed.

Comment: @ManojGoel Can you please share your bablerc and webpack config files?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue ,When is am switch to parcel not webpack.
Here is my index.js file code ,Please replace the "root" with "app".

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
 <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I think its working fine now.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "parceljs APP Data",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel serve src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```